# Laravel prevent user action

Tags: php, laravel

I use laravel 5.6 for my project and entrust to handle users/roles/permissions.

But now I'm facing another problem and I don't know which way to go.

Basically on my database, I have a "general" table with x columns. Each columns represent a part of my app so there's only one row.

For example, I can have a "edit-post" columns with 0, 1 or 2.

How to prevent user to access to get/post routes based on database value ?

If edit-post equal 2, user can view edit page / post edit data.

Must I use middleware ? gates ? anything else ?

Thank for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your users' permission and activity according to users role . Like Admin , Moderator or Super admin  . Just create a table that holds the role names with user relations and hook up authentication  with it . So every time an user log in he can go to his specific territory and perform your defined activity .
[You can see this for better understanding](https://www.5balloons.info/user-role-based-authentication-and-access-control-in-laravel/)

Comment: It's not related to user's permission. Every users can't edit post if edit_post = 1

Answer (score 1):

As `Raggib` said: create a users table permission:

```
 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('role');
});
```

Create a middleware to check if the user has the permissions to access the record you are trying to protect:

```
if($loggedUser->role != 'admin'){
    // cannot edit
}
```

The advantage of this method is that you can add roles later. This will give you the possibility to better control who can access which records.

Comment: I must prevent all users (include admin) to perform actions. So if edit_post = 1 then all users can't edit_post.

Comment: I don't know which requirements your application have but I would highly advise you to use the method above. One day the client (or even you) may change its mind and you will need one more role (e.g. a user can edit all the posts no matter what). Then the only thing you need to check is his role. If you would like to do it with only `edit_post = 1` then you just need to create a middleware and apply this middleware to the route you need to check or even check the `edit_post` before performing the action on the post

Comment: Client is me :) in middleware, how can I access to eloquent model ?

Comment: That is the problem. If you have a middleware you will need to *ALWAYS* pass the ID or something that identifies the model. Something like `<input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{ $post->id }}">` and in the middleware you would get that model to check if the logged user could perform that action