# Laravel permission issue with users

Tags: laravel

I have admin dashboard and users like admin,developer,end users
I have permision to each roles

I have Voyageradminmiddleware to prevent access to other users.

```
<?php

namespace TCG\Voyager\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use TCG\Voyager\Facades\Voyager;

class VoyagerAdminMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure                 $next
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!Auth::guest()) {
            $user = Voyager::model('User')->find(Auth::id());

            return $user->hasPermission('browse_admin') 
                        ? $next($request) 
                        : redirect('/');
        }

        return redirect(route('voyager.login'));
    }
}
```

Now my problem is that only admin can access dashborad other users can't.

```
return $user->hasPermission('browse_admin') 
            ? $next($request) 
            : $next($request);
```

This code is working but if i use this, there is permission issue,any user can access others permission when they hit direct url.
I am very new to laravel.please help me.

Comment: I think it can help you

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52456789/laravel-prevent-user-action/52456886#52456886

Comment: @Ezra: Where do you want to redirect other users?